# Stuck in recursion in rangeProduct function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am a beginner in Haskell and I am stuck in a simple recursion function.

I am trying to define a function rangeProduct which when given natural numbers m and n returns the product

m*(m+1)*...*(n-1)*n

The function should return 0 when n is smaller than m.

What I've tried:

```
rangeProduct :: Int -> Int -> Int
rangeProduct m n
    | m > n     = 0
    | otherwise = m * n * rangeProduct (m+1)(n-1)
```

But this is wrong because in the otherwise guard, when m gets bigger and n smaller, at some point m will get bigger than n and it will get 0 causing all what it has done so far to get multiplied by zero, resulting in 0 everytime I run the function.

I know the answer is simple but I am stuck. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother incrementing and decrementing at the same time?  Just go in one direction:

```
rangeProduct m n
    | m >  n    = 0
    | m == n    = n
    | otherwise = m * rangeProduct (m + 1) n
```

Although you could easily define this without recursion as

```
rangeProduct :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
rangeProduct m n
    | m > n     = 0
    | otherwise = product [m..n]
```